# Trying to add more cases, not working as intended

Tags: javascript

My goal is to make a little program that understands human words.

I decided to start out with simple math before making other stuff but something is wrong.

So far the human reader can do addition, but I want it do more operations like subtraction, multiplication, division, etc. I have this part of the code that handles cases, basically if you tell it to 'add ...' it should add, you get the idea, And it looks like this:

```
switch (operator) {
    case "add":
      return numbers.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b));
```

Great, so I figured I should just make another case and just do "subtract" and just do Number(a) - Number(b) right?

Well thats where it goes flop, if I tell it to subtract 2 from 5, it gives me a response that looks like this:

```
undefined
```

When what I want it to say is:

```
-3
```

How can I solve this issue?
Full Source Code:

```
function output(func) {
  console.log(func)
}

function read(str) {
  const dl = str.split(' ');
  const operator = dl.shift(x => x.includes("add", "sub", "mul", "div"))
  const numbers = dl.filter(x => Number(x))
  switch (operator) {
    case "add":
      return numbers.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b));
    case "subtract":
      return numbers.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) - Number(b));
  }
}

const result = read(
  "add 6 and 4"
)

output(result)
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your code to see what the "operator" is? Is it actually "subtract" or "sub", or something else entirely? Make sure the `case` matches that, then it should work.

Comment: @computercarguy Isn't it a phenomenon when you try doing one thing once, it doesn't work, then you try it again, it somehow works? Anyways, it worked and thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that is a phenomenon. Einstein's definition of insanity is "doing the same thing over and expecting different results". The definition of software development is "doing the same thing over and over again and getting different results". ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it works fine.

```js
function output(func) {
  console.log(func)
}

function read(str) {
  const dl = str.split(' ');
  const operator = dl.shift(x => x.includes("add", "sub", "mul", "div"))
  const numbers = dl.filter(x => Number(x))
  switch (operator) {
    case "add":
      return numbers.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b));
    case "subtract":
      return numbers.reduce((a, b) => Number(a) - Number(b));
  }
}

output(read(
  "add 6 and 4"
))

output(read(
  "subtract 6 and 4"
))

output(read(
  "subtract 2 and 5"
))

output(read(
  "sub 2 and 5"
))
```

Comment: hmm, interesting, but doesn't the subtraction operator have to match with the case for it to work or am i jumping over something?

Comment: `"subtract"` does `include` `"sub"` so I think that's why it works. For example, if you write just `sub` it doesn't work because your switch-case statement only has `"subtract"`.